# Basic Rock-Paper-Scissors implementation

Tags: java, game, lambda, rock-paper-scissors

I decided to try to make a simple RPS implementation in Java 8, the following notes should be said first:

- At a later point it should support RPSLS aswell, as any other Gesture-game variant.
- At a later point it should support different views, for example a graphical one.
- I have made a special `ConsoleReader` class which allows me to kill reading from `System.in` without closing the stream.

I would like comments on:

- Everything
- Concurrency issues
- Variable, method and javadoc naming and wording

The code should be quite self-explanatory.

```
/**
 * Class that provides a console reader, from which other classes can read.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public class ConsoleReader implements Runnable {
    /** Synchronized mapping from objects to a list of string consumers to consume input lines. */
    private final static Map<Object, List<Consumer<String>>> CONSUMER_MAP = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    /** Synchronized mapping from objects to a blocking queue of strings to read input lines while maintaining blocking behaviour. */
    private final static Map<Object, BlockingQueue<String>> BLOCKING_QUEUE_MAP = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    /**
     * Adds a consumer on the object you pass. When console input happens, the consumer will be triggered.
     * 
     * @param object    The object to which the consumers belong
     * @param consumer  The consumer to handle new input
     */
    public static void addConsumer(final Object object, final Consumer<String> consumer) {
        ensureKey(object, CONSUMER_MAP, ArrayList::new);
        CONSUMER_MAP.get(object).add(consumer);
    }

    /**
     * Removes all consumers related to the object you pass.
     * 
     * @param object    The object to which consumers might be attached
     */
    public static void removeConsumers(final Object object) {
        CONSUMER_MAP.remove(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            try {
                for (Map.Entry<Object, BlockingQueue<String>> entry : BLOCKING_QUEUE_MAP.entrySet()) {
                    entry.getValue().put(nextLine);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            CONSUMER_MAP.forEach((obj, list) -> list.forEach(consumer -> consumer.accept(nextLine)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Waits for a new line of input and then returns it.
     * 
     * Per object a new queue gets created, such that taking away the line from one queue does not mean that other objects cannot read it anymore.
     * 
     * @param object    The object that asks to read the next line
     * @return  The next line from System.in
     * @throws InterruptedException     If the thread has been interrupted
     */
    public static String nextLine(final Object object) throws InterruptedException {
        ensureKey(object, BLOCKING_QUEUE_MAP, LinkedBlockingQueue::new);
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = BLOCKING_QUEUE_MAP.get(object);
        String nextLine = queue.take();
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            BLOCKING_QUEUE_MAP.remove(object);
        }
        return nextLine;
    }

    /**
     * Ensures that the key has an empty structure attached to it.
     * 
     * @param <V>   The type of structure of Map<Object, V>
     * @param object    The key of the map
     * @param map   The map on which to ensure a value exists
     * @param supplier  A supplier to supply an empty structure
     */
    private static <V> void ensureKey(final Object object, final Map<Object, V> map, final Supplier<V> supplier) {
        if (!map.containsKey(object)) {
            map.put(object, supplier.get());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Interface to extend when implementing actions.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public interface Action { }
```

---

```
/**
 * Interface that all types of gestures should extend.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public interface Gesture {
    /**
     * Lists from which gestures this gesture wins.
     * 
     * @return  A list describing from which gestures this gesture wins
     */
    public List<? extends Gesture> listWinsFrom();

    /**
     * Lists to which gestures this gesture ties.
     * 
     * @return  A list describing to which gestures this gesture ties
     */
    public List<? extends Gesture> listTiesTo();

    /**
     * Lists from which gestures this gesture loses.
     * 
     * @return  A list describing from which gestures this gesture loses
     */
    public List<? extends Gesture> listLosesFrom();

    /**
     * Returns whether this gesture wins from the other gesture
     * 
     * @param <G>   The concrete type of the gesture
     * @param gesture   The other gesture
     * @return  Whether this gesture wins from the other gesture
     */
    default public <G extends Gesture> boolean winsFrom(final G gesture) {
        return listWinsFrom().contains(gesture);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether this gesture ties to the other gesture
     * 
     * @param <G>   The concrete type of the gesture
     * @param gesture   The other gesture
     * @return  Whether this gesture ties to the other gesture
     */
    default public <G extends Gesture> boolean tiesTo(final G gesture) {
        return listTiesTo().contains(gesture);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether this gesture loses from the other gesture
     * 
     * @param <G>   The concrete type of the gesture
     * @param gesture   The other gesture
     * @return  Whether this gesture loses from the other gesture
     */
    default public <G extends Gesture> boolean losesFrom(final G gesture) {
        return listLosesFrom().contains(gesture);
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * An enum providing the RPS gestures.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public enum RPSGesture implements Gesture, Action, GestureRPSRules {
    ROCK,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS;

    @Override
    public List<RPSGesture> listWinsFrom() {
        return winMapping().get(this);
    }

    @Override
    public List<RPSGesture> listTiesTo() {
        return tieMapping().get(this);
    }

    @Override
    public List<RPSGesture> listLosesFrom() {
        return loseMapping().get(this);
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Provides the rules of a specific gesture, meaning when one wins, ties or loses.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 * @param <T> The type of gesture
 */
public interface GestureRules<T extends Gesture> {
    /**
     * Returns a mapping from the gestures to which gestures they win from.
     * 
     * @return  A mapping from the gestures to which gestures they win from
     */
    public Map<T, List<T>> winMapping();

    /**
     * Returns a mapping from the gestures to which gestures they tie to.
     * 
     * @return  A mapping from the gestures to which gestures they tie to
     */
    public Map<T, List<T>> tieMapping();

    /**
     * Returns a mapping from the gestures to which gestures they lose from.
     * 
     * @return  A mapping from the gestures to which gestures they lose from
     */
    public Map<T, List<T>> loseMapping();
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Provides an implementation for the GestureRules when considering RPS gestures.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public interface GestureRPSRules extends GestureRules<RPSGesture> {
    @Override
    default public Map<RPSGesture, List<RPSGesture>> winMapping() {
        Map<RPSGesture, List<RPSGesture>> mapping = new HashMap<>();
        mapping.put(ROCK, Arrays.asList(SCISSORS));
        mapping.put(PAPER, Arrays.asList(ROCK));
        mapping.put(SCISSORS, Arrays.asList(PAPER));
        return mapping;
    }

    @Override
    default public Map<RPSGesture, List<RPSGesture>> tieMapping() {
        Map<RPSGesture, List<RPSGesture>> mapping = new HashMap<>();
        mapping.put(ROCK, Arrays.asList(ROCK));
        mapping.put(PAPER, Arrays.asList(PAPER));
        mapping.put(SCISSORS, Arrays.asList(SCISSORS));
        return mapping;
    }

    @Override
    default public Map<RPSGesture, List<RPSGesture>> loseMapping() {
        Map<RPSGesture, List<RPSGesture>> mapping = new HashMap<>();
        mapping.put(ROCK, Arrays.asList(PAPER));
        mapping.put(PAPER, Arrays.asList(SCISSORS));
        mapping.put(SCISSORS, Arrays.asList(ROCK));
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Interface to extend when implementing results.
 * 
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public interface Result { }
```

---

```
/**
 * Enum listing the possible results of a RPS game.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public enum RPSResult implements Result {
    WIN,
    TIE,
    LOSS;
}
```

---

```
/**
 * An interface holding a player that can play any type of game.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 * @param <A> The type of the action
 * @param <R> The type of the result
 */
public interface Player<A extends Action, R extends Result> {
    /**
     * Processes when some player has done some action and obtained some result.
     * 
     * @param target    The player that performed the action
     * @param action    The action the player performed
     * @param result    The result of the action the player has performed
     */
    default public void onPostAction(final Player<A, R> target, final A action, final R result) { }

    /**
     * Does the action of the player.
     * 
     * @return The action the player has done
     */
    public A doAction();

    /**
     * Does the backup action of the player.
     * 
     * This will get called when the normal action has timed out.
     * 
     * @return The backup action the player has done
     */
    public A doActionBackup();

    /**
     * Performs the action of the player with a timeout on an Executor.
     * 
     * This will execute the normal action of the player waiting for a maximum specified time, if a timeout occurs then it will default to the backup action.
     * 
     * @param executor  The Executor on which the action needs to be executed
     * @param period    The time period it may take until the action gets a timeout
     * @param unit      The time unit of the period
     * @return  The action performed by the player
     */
    default public A doActionWithTimeout(final Executor executor, final int period, final TimeUnit unit) {
        FutureTask<A> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(this::doAction);
        executor.execute(futureTask);
        try {
            return futureTask.get(period, unit);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            futureTask.cancel(true);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return doActionBackup();
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            timeout();
            futureTask.cancel(true);
            return doActionBackup();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Does something when a timeout has occured.
     */
    default public void timeout() { }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * A player that is able to play any gesture related game.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 * @param <A> The type of action
 * @param <R> The type of result
 */
abstract public class GesturePlayer<A extends Action, R extends Result> implements Player<A, R> {
    /** List of actions that the player can execute. **/
    protected final List<A> actions;

    /** A Random instance. **/
    private final Random random = new Random();

    /**
     * Constructs the GesturePlayer.
     * 
     * @param actions   The list of actions that can be used
     */
    public GesturePlayer(final List<A> actions) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(actions);
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random action.
     * 
     * @return  A random action.
     */
    protected A getRandomAction() {
        return actions.get(random.nextInt(actions.size()));
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * A player that is able to play RPS.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
abstract public class RPSPlayer extends GesturePlayer<RPSGesture, RPSResult> {
    /** The RPSView interface. */
    protected final RPSView rpsView;

    /**
     * Constructs the RPSPlayer with the RPSView interface as argument.
     * 
     * @param rpsView   The RPS view
     */
    public RPSPlayer(final RPSView rpsView) {
        super(Arrays.asList(RPSGesture.values()));
        this.rpsView = rpsView;
    }

    @Override
    public RPSGesture doActionBackup() {
        return getRandomAction();
    }

    @Override
    public void timeout() {
        rpsView.enterGestureTimeout(this);
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * A human player that can play RPS.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public class RPSHumanPlayer extends RPSPlayer {  
    public RPSHumanPlayer(final RPSView rpsView) {
        super(rpsView);
    }

    @Override
    public RPSGesture doAction() {
        Optional<RPSGesture> gesture;
        try {
            gesture = askInput();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return doActionBackup();
        }
        while (!gesture.isPresent()) {
            rpsView.gestureNotRecognized(actions);
            try {
                gesture = askInput();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return doActionBackup();
            }
        }
        return gesture.get();
    }

    /**
     * Asks for user input.
     * 
     * @return  The user input, converted to a RPS gesture.
     * @throws InterruptedException     If the method gets interrupted.
     */
    private Optional<RPSGesture> askInput() throws InterruptedException {
        rpsView.pleaseEnterGesture();
        return parseRaw(rpsView.readGestureInput());
    }

    private Optional<RPSGesture> parseRaw(final String raw) {
        List<RPSGesture> gestures = actions.stream()
                .filter(action -> action.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(raw.toLowerCase()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ((gestures.size() == 1) ? Optional.of(gestures.get(0)) : Optional.empty());
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * An AI player that can play RPS.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public class RPSSimpleAIPlayer extends RPSPlayer {
    /**
     * Constructs the RPSSimpleAIPlayer.
     * 
     * @param rpsView   The RPS view
     */
    public RPSSimpleAIPlayer(final RPSView rpsView) {
        super(rpsView);
    }

    @Override
    public RPSGesture doAction() {
        return getRandomAction();
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * An interface that can be used for playing any type of game. 
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 * @param <A> The type of action in the game
 * @param <R> The type of result in the game
 * @param <P> The type of player in the game
 */
public interface Game<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends Player<A, R>> {
    /**
     * Adds a player to this game.
     * 
     * @param player    The new player
     */
    public void addPlayer(final P player);

    /**
     * Plays one round of the game. 
     */
    public void playRound();

    /**
     * Default implementation of playing a game.
     * 
     * This will play a game that lasts forever.
     */
    default public void playGame() {
        boolean playing = true;
        while (playing) {
            playRound();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the result of a player after having played the current round.
     * 
     * @param playerActions A mapping from the players to their actions
     * @param forPlayer The player for which to determine the result
     * @param forAction The action that belongs to the player
     * @return  The result of the player for this round
     */
    public R determinePlayerResult(final Map<P, A> playerActions, final P forPlayer, final A forAction);
}
```

---

```
/**
 * An abstract class that provides some basic implementations of the Game.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 * @param <A> The type of action in the game
 * @param <R> The type of result in the game
 * @param <P> The type of player in the game
 */
abstract public class AbstractGame<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends Player<A, R>> implements Game<A, R, P> {
    /** A list holding all players. */
    protected final List<P> players = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void addPlayer(final P player) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(player);
        players.add(player);
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * A class providing an implementation for a RPS game.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public class RPSGame extends AbstractGame<RPSGesture, RPSResult, RPSPlayer> {
    /** An executor service to run the player calculations on, initialized to two times the available cores. */
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2);

    /** The RPSView interface. */
    private final RPSView rpsView;

    /**
     * Construcs the RPSGame with the RPSView interface as argument.
     * 
     * @param rpsView   The RPS view
     */
    public RPSGame(final RPSView rpsView) {
        this.rpsView = rpsView;
    }

    @Override
    public void playRound() {
        Map<RPSPlayer, RPSGesture> playerGestures = players.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        player -> player, 
                        player -> player.doActionWithTimeout(executorService, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                );
        playerGestures.forEach((player, gesture) -> {
            RPSResult result = determinePlayerResult(playerGestures, player, gesture);
            players.forEach(p -> p.onPostAction(player, gesture, result));
            rpsView.processPlayerAction(player, gesture, result);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public RPSResult determinePlayerResult(final Map<RPSPlayer, RPSGesture> playerActions, final RPSPlayer forPlayer, final RPSGesture forGesture) {
        int wins = 0;
        int ties = 0;
        int losses = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<RPSPlayer, RPSGesture> entry : playerActions.entrySet()) {
            RPSPlayer player = entry.getKey();
            RPSGesture gesture = entry.getValue();
            if (player.equals(forPlayer)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (forGesture.winsFrom(gesture)) {
                wins++;
            }
            else if (forGesture.tiesTo(gesture)) {
                ties++;
            }
            else if (forGesture.losesFrom(gesture)) {
                losses++;
            }
        }
        int max = IntStream.of(wins, ties, losses).max().getAsInt();
        if (max == wins) {
            return RPSResult.WIN;
        }
        else if (max == ties) {
            return RPSResult.TIE;
        }
        else {
            return RPSResult.LOSS;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Interface having all input/output related methods for a RPSGame.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public interface RPSView {
    /**
     * Processes a player action.
     * 
     * @param player    The player on which the action occured
     * @param gesture   The gesture the player has used
     * @param result    The result of using that gesture in that specific round
     */
    public void processPlayerAction(final RPSPlayer player, final RPSGesture gesture, final RPSResult result);

    /**
     * Processes what happens when the gesture has not been recognized.
     * 
     * @param gestures  All available gestures
     */
    public void gestureNotRecognized(final List<RPSGesture> gestures);

    /**
     * Processes what happens when the player should provide his/her gesture.
     */
    public void pleaseEnterGesture();

    /**
     * Processes what happens when the player has a timeout.
     * 
     * @param player    The player that had received a timeout
     */
    public void enterGestureTimeout(final RPSPlayer player);

    /**
     * Processes what happens when the player needs to enter his gesture.
     * 
     * @return  The entered gesture in string format
     * @throws InterruptedException     If waiting for the gesture to be entered has been interrupted
     */
    public String readGestureInput() throws InterruptedException;
}
```

---

```
/**
 * Class providing the console implementation of the RPSView.
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public class ConsoleRPSView implements RPSView {
    @Override
    public void processPlayerAction(final RPSPlayer player, final RPSGesture gesture, final RPSResult result) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(player);
        Objects.requireNonNull(gesture);
        Objects.requireNonNull(result);
        if (player instanceof RPSHumanPlayer) {
            System.out.println("I played " + gesture + " and the result was a " + result);
        }
        else if (player instanceof RPSSimpleAIPlayer) {
            System.out.println("The AI played " + gesture + " and the result was a " + result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void gestureNotRecognized(final List<RPSGesture> gestures) {
        System.out.println("Your gesture was nog recognized or ambigious, please choose from: " + 
                String.join(", ", gestures.stream().map(RPSGesture::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }

    @Override
    public void pleaseEnterGesture() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your gesture: ");
    }

    @Override
    public String readGestureInput() throws InterruptedException {
        return ConsoleReader.nextLine(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void enterGestureTimeout(final RPSPlayer player) {
        if (player instanceof RPSHumanPlayer) {
            System.out.println("You have not entered your gesture in time.");
        } else if (player instanceof RPSSimpleAIPlayer) {
            System.out.println("The AI has not entered his gesture in time.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
/**
 * The main class
 *
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public class RPSGameMain {
    private void init() {
        new Thread(new ConsoleReader()).start();
        RPSView consoleRPSView = new ConsoleRPSView();
        RPSGame rpsGame = new RPSGame(consoleRPSView);
        rpsGame.addPlayer(new RPSHumanPlayer(consoleRPSView));
        rpsGame.addPlayer(new RPSSimpleAIPlayer(consoleRPSView));
        rpsGame.playGame();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RPSGameMain().init();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the tests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- I like your usage of Java 8. I'm learning a lot just by reading your code. I'm loving Java 8 a lot and I haven't even used it myself yet.
- Use a `GestureRule` class. Take a look at [The Mug's Main class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36426/rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-challenge-take-2) and/or [The Monkey's static initializer in his enum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36394/rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-as-a-code-style-and-challenge). Your current way is error prone and causes some duplicated code. Currently you can by accident create a Gesture that both wins, loses and ties another gesture. That really shouldn't be possible. I'd recommend using a method such as `gesture.fight(otherGesture)` that returns a `RPSResult` to make sure that a fight between one gesture and another cannot be both a win and a loss at the same time.
- You're currently not using the `onPostAction` method, and I do wonder whether you're gonna need it at all. And if you are going to need it, it can likely be made in a different/better way. By getting rid of it / doing it differently you also get rid of the `R extends Result` generic part of your `Player` interface/class(es). An option would be to use `onPostRound(Map<RPSPlayer, RPSGesture> gestures)` (using only the 'A' and 'P' generics) and do a for-each on the gestures you're interested in. Because technically, players make their moves at the same time.
- Your `Action` and `Result` interfaces only seems to be *marker interfaces*, you don't really need them. If you remove them it will decrease your generic dependencies and you can write:

  ```
  public interface Game<A, R, P extends Player<A, R>> {
  ```
- Interface methods doesn't need to be declared `public`, they're public automatically.
- In your `playGame` method, why do you declare a boolean variable instead of using `while (true)`?
- You're using `newFixedThreadPool` which means that your number of threads cannot go above the specified amount. Instead consider using a cached thread pool which will create as many threads as needed while keeping a specified number of threads whether they're busy or not. By using a fixed thread pool you will likely have several threads that will *never* have anything to do.
- Use a `toString` method in your different `RPSPlayer` classes or a `player.isAI()` method instead of using `instanceof` in your ConsoleRPSView. Using `instanceof` outside an `.equals` method is not good practice, it can mostly be avoided. Use polymorphism and better interfaces instead.

  ```
  System.out.println(player + " played " + gesture + " and the result was a " + result);
  ...
  if (!player.isAI())
      System.out.println("You have not entered your gesture in time.");
  ```
- Typo: `System.out.println("Your gesture was nog recognized` - nog --> not. 'nog' means 'probably' in Swedish so if reading this in a combined English-Swedish way it'd be quite funny...
- Your `RPSGameMain.init` method does more than just initializing, doesn't it? I'd recommend either splitting into two methods or rename it to `start` or similar.
- Overall your code quality is good, it is easy to read and mostly easy to understand.
- I like the way you've decoupled your "console view" from your "model" with an interface :)

Answer (score 7):

As a relatively minor thing, I think there are some issues with over commenting. For example:

```
/**
     * Returns a random action.
     * 
     * @return  A random action.
     */
    protected A getRandomAction() {
        return actions.get(random.nextInt(actions.size()));
    }
```

This is a clearly written method, it's method name concisely explains what it does, and there are no parameters to trip up a user.  It's got a single line and it's very readable. In fact it takes me longer to read the comment than the code. From [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882): a comment should be included if it makes the code easier to understand. Here, we have lots of repetition.

Comment: Javadoc is not the same as comments

Comment: Unfortunately, rolfl is right here. Often there is a requirement on code to have appropriate Javadoc, in this case skiwi put that as a requirement on himself apparently. This is still an answer worth thinking about though. But writing non-duplicated Javadoc is hard.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by `ConsoleReader`.  It seems too complex.  I honestly did not spend that much time reading your code, so maybe I did not understand correctly.

- In the method declarations, `player`, `key` or `id` would probably be better variables names than `object`.
- I don't like that `ConsoleRPSReader` is highly dependent on `ConsoleReader` but that dependency is not visible.  You should probably have the constructor of `ConsoleRPSReader` taking a `ConsoleReader` as argument.
- Is `ConsoleReader` just a provider of static methods? a singleton?  Maybe it should be a normal class, but you make the constructor private and provide a static method to get the singleton.  You could then make member variables and methods non-static.
- `ConsoleReader.run()` puts a new line in *all* the queues.  Is that a bug?  `Console.nextLine(key)` will read the new line for all keys.
- To reduce complexity, maybe you could break `ConsoleReader` in one parent class that just reads from input, than one sub-class which can have "observers".  I'm still not sure why you specify some key in `Console.nextLine(key)`, so I'm not sure if that should be a different sub-class.

Minor details:

- Avoid using "you" in Javadoc.
- Instead of `for(Entry x : map.entrySet()) { x.getValue()...}`, you can use `for (Val v : map.values()) { v...}`.  I think it is cleaner, but it's arguable.